# (Xcode/Swift) Loading dylibs with dependencies

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, dylib

I'm having trouble using dynamic libraries in an Xcode Swift project.

Here's what I've done so far:

- in my code, I open the dylib with `dlopen` (and then I use `dlsym` to load the functions contained in it).
- the dylib file is referenced in my Xcode project, and is copied inside the "Frameworks" folder of my app during the build (`Target → Build Phases → Copy Files`).
- I also added `@executable_path/../Frameworks` in the `Runpath Search Path` field in `Build Settings`.

All of this works pretty well for a simple dylib, but when the library I try to use has dependencies, I get the following error:

```
dlopen(myLib.dylib, 2): Library not loaded: dependency.dylib
Referenced from: [...]/MyApp./Contents/Frameworks/myLib.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

I did manage to bypass the problem by changing the value of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but in order to do this, I need to disable the app sandbox - which needs to be activated for my app.